# PHP - AJAX - Validate simple login form (check if user is a especified one)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, input

I have this simple form I'm testing. It's just a test for the beginning of a form that will be improved later on; I only need it to work correctly. I still don't have the database ready, so in my code I have two users that I want to pass as 'registered'.

Here's the code for the form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>User: </label>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="usuario" />
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="boton-submit" name="submit" onClick="login()">Sign In</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

These two inputs are validated with JavaScript, and the values are sent through AJAX.

This is the code (only the AJAX part, the rest are only validations and they work fine):

```
function login(){

if(validationLogin()){
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/MyApp/extras/processLogin.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: {"user": user, 
                       "password": password, 
                       },
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {    
                    console.log("Processing...");
                },
                success: 
                      function(data){
                        if(data == "OK"){
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost/MyApp/loginSuccess.php"; 
                        }else{
                            window.location.href = "http://localhost/MyApp/loginFail.php";
                        }
                    }

        });

    }else{
        //alert("Incorrect data");
    }
}
```

And this is code in the PHP file:

```
<?php

session_start();

$user = "";
$password = "";
$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['user'])){
       if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
       $user = $_POST['user'];
    }else{
       $errors = 1;
    }
    }else{
       $errors = $errors;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['password'])){
       if(!empty($_POST['password'])){
       $password = $_POST['password'];
    }else{
       $errors = 1;
    }
    }else{
       $errors = $errors;
    }

$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

//TEST: Check if user is --> LAURA 123456 or LUIS 567899
if((($user == "LAURA") && ($password == "123456")) || (($user == "LUIS") && 
   ($password == "567899"))){
    $data = "OK";
    echo $data;
    //header("location: ../loginSuccess.php");
}else{
    $data = "ERROR";
    echo $data;
    //echo "No se encontró usuario";
    //header("location: ../loginFail.php");
}

}
```

At the beginning, I had an action in the form that sent data to the PHP directly, and in that way it worked fine --> if user was LAURA or LUIS it would redirect to loginSuccess.php and greeted the user, if not, it would redirect to loginFail.php (that's why the headers are commented)

I just want to test that this functions, but when I modified the code to use AJAX, it always fails, even if the user is LAURA or LUIS, it redirects to the loginFail page...

I suspect there is some problem in the success function in the AJAX call.

Any help is appreciated :) Have a nice day!

Comment: If you are redirecting the user after form submit anyways then why bring AJAX in the mix in the first place? Simply submit the form to your php and redirect with PHP itself. Cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `submit` index your `$_POST` array, so this condition `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ ...` will always fail. Remove this conditional check `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ ... }` entirely, and refactor your backend PHP code in the following way,

```
    <?php
        session_start();

        $user = "";
        $password = "";
        $errors = array();

        if(isset($_POST['user'])){
            if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
                $user = $_POST['user'];
            }else{
                $errors = 1;
            }
        }else{
           $errors = $errors;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['password'])){
           if(!empty($_POST['password'])){
                $password = $_POST['password'];
            }else{
                $errors = 1;
            }
        }else{
           $errors = $errors;
        }

        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

        //TEST: Check if user is --> LAURA 123456 or LUIS 567899
        if((($user == "LAURA") && ($password == "123456")) || (($user == "LUIS") && 
           ($password == "567899"))){
            $data = "OK";
            echo $data;
            //header("location: ../loginSuccess.php");
        }else{
            $data = "ERROR";
            echo $data;
            //echo "No se encontró usuario";
            //header("location: ../loginFail.php");
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I've removed the if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ ... }, you're right. As regards user and password not being defined, they are indeed, their values from the validations within validationLogin() which I didn't post because I thought they were unnecessary (the validations themselves are working ok) Now it recognizes any user and redirects to loginSuccess.php :/

Comment: @xragdollqueen The code is working fine on my end. Did you make any additional changes in the code?

Comment: @xragdollqueen You're welcome! Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)